# Is there a way to filter data set with part of a data value in r?

Tags: r

Help in R. 
I have a data set with some of the columns have values of a string, like " bitumen coal", " xxx oil", " yyy oil", "zzz coal, ....
What I want is to find a way to subset only data that contain the text "coal" in that column. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at "subset".
You should be able to do something like:

```
mySub = subset(data, columnName=="coal")
```

If you're looking for more text flexibility you can use grepl:

```
mySub  = subset(data, grepl("oil", data$columnName))
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will dig more on "grep"

Answer (score 0):

You should look at grep. Type:

```
?grep
```

An example:

```
a <- c("a coal", "a coal", "c oil")
# use grep function
a[grep("coal", a)]
```

Indeed you should learn about regex (regular expresions). You won't regret the time spent on it. They are every where. (Lately I even found out that you can even use them within ms excel)